# How to style author id in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

How to add css to specific wordpress user to hide plugin fiction over front end? I installed the wp-about-author plugin but I need to set as hidden for admin user. So when the admin make any blog post then the wp-about-author wont be displayed. Unfortunately no feedback from the plugin developer. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS way is not recommended since the user can check out actual DOM by view the source.
Instead, You can prevent from even showing up in the DOM Tree by modifying a plugin php file.

```
$level = get_the_author_meta('user_level');

if ($level == 10) {
    return;
}
```

Add this line to `wp-about-author.php` on line #31.
This works, I tested.

Comment: Ok, this one removed the plugin but I need this to be removed only when an admin user wrote a blog post. Is there any option to block the plugin when an admin publish the post? So the rest of the contributor, editor could have the wp-about-author displayed.

Comment: I figured out what you wanted, so changed it to your need again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update plugin better then hack css :) You can add to `wp-about-author.php` on line #102 something like:

```
if (wp_admin()) $return_content = '';
```

I didn't check it, but might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but its does not work. The above blocked the entire post contents.